# Why does Typescript not compile this InversifyJS decorator?

Tags: typescript, inversifyjs

I'm copying the Inversify documentation almost exactly (version 1.2.2) and it fails to compile, giving me Typescript error TS1238. Why?

```
'use strict';
import './tools/typescriptImports';
import IServer = require('./iServer.ts');
import IDatabase = require('../database/iDatabase');
import express = require('express');
import bodyParser = require('body-parser');
import config = require('../config');
import types = require('../tools/types.ts');
import _ = require('lodash');
import async_ = require('async');
import { Inject } from "inversify";

@Inject("IDatabase") // <- error TS1238: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression. Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
class Server implements IServer
{
    db : IDatabase;
    expressApp : express.Express;

    constructor(db : IDatabase)
    {
        this.db = db;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks like @Inject is a property decoration not a class decoration. Try decorating the parameters in the constructor.

Comment: Their code seems to be saying something else. https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/source/inject_annotation.ts (if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: wild guess: I understand from https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS that you are supposed to use an interface in `@Inject` decorator (i.e. `@Inject("FooInterface")`). Is `IDatabase` really an interface?

Comment: that might be, but the error states pretty clearly that the decorator is not usable as a class decorator. :)

Comment: @toskv It's a parameter decorator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/source/inject_annotation.ts), Inject can in no way be a class decorator. Class decorators are expected to return a constructor function, but the decorator returned by Inject is returning `void` (Inject is a decorator factory, which is returning the decorator function itself).

Inject in fact returns a *parameter* decorator, and - as its name implies - should be used to decorate a method parameter:

```
class Server implements IServer
{
    db : IDatabase;
    expressApp : express.Express;

    constructor(@Inject("IDatabase") db : IDatabase)
    {
        this.db = db;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, confirmed by the library creators: https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/issues/62#issuecomment-178521097. I guess I should find a less buggy IoC library .

Answer (score 2):

We just release InversifyJS version 1.3.0 and it allows you to apply the Inject decorator to a class:

```
interface IKatana {
    power : number;
    hit() : boolean;
}

interface IShuriken {
    power : number;
    throw() : boolean;
}

@Inject("IKatana", "IShuriken")
class Warrior {

    private _katana : IKatana;
    private _shuriken : IShuriken;

    constructor(katana : IKatana, shuriken : IShuriken) {
        this._katana = katana;
        this._shuriken = shuriken;
    }
}
```

The following is not supported anymore:

```
class Warrior {

    private _katana : IKatana;
    private _shuriken : IShuriken;

    constructor(
        @Inject("IKatana") katana : IKatana, 
        @Inject("IShuriken") shuriken : IShuriken
    ) {
        this._katana = katana;
        this._shuriken = shuriken;
    }
}
```

Injections based on naming conventions are also not supported anymore:

```
class Warrior {

    private _katana : IKatana;
    private _shuriken : IShuriken;

    constructor(IKatana: IKatana, IShuriken: IShuriken) {
        this._katana = IKatana;
        this._shuriken = IShuriken;
    }
}
```